# C++ class "upgrade" with minimal boiler-plate

Tags: c++, serialization, dynamic, reflection, types

Let's say I have the following:

```
struct C1 { int w; }
struct B1 { int x; int y; int z; C1 c; };
struct A1 { int x; int y; int z; B1 b; };
struct C2 { long w; short t; }
struct B2 { int x; int y; int z; C2 c; };
struct A2 { int x; int y; int z; B2 b; };
```

and I want to implement the function

```
A2 upgrade(const A1 &a1);
```

such that it takes the a1 object, and creates an a2 object from it (assume that `a2.w = a1.w` and `a2.t = 6`).

An ideal (but impossible to my knowledge) implementation would look as following:

```
A2 upgrade(const A1 &a1) {
    dynamic d = to_dyn(a1);
    d["b"]["c"]["w"] = (long)d["b"]["c"]["w"];
    d["b"]["c"]["z"] = (short)5;
    A2 a2 = from_dyn(d);
    return a2;
}
```

How close can I get to this in actual C++?

Answer (score 1):

As all the classes are aggregates, the most concise and straight-forward would be using aggregate-initialization:

```
A2 upgrade(const A1& a) {
    return {a.x, a.y, a.z, {a.b.x, a.b.y, a.b.z, {a.b.c.w, (short)5}}};
}
```

C++ does not have any facility to iterate over a types members, neither compile-time nor runtime.
There are people working on a proposal to add such a compile-time facility to the language, but it still needs much work.

Comment: I am trying to avoid this since this requires listing all the fields in the upgrade code.

Comment: @tohava: There is no way (yet). Added something to that effect, with details. Unless, of course, you are prepared to go outside the standard: Just `memcpy`, and then set the rest. Should work in practice, though it's not guaranteed.

Comment: @Deduplicator That won't work in practice if the `C1`/`C2` field is not the **last** one in both of them.

Comment: @Deduplicator the layout compatible rules might  make it rather closer to being standardized than you might think.  The non-sub-struct fields are definitely layout compatible.  The prefix of the one struct is layout compatible with the other.  I would not know without standard delving if the prefix of the composite was also layout compatible, but would be surprised neither way.  Now, this only works for trivially copyable data, naturally.

Comment: @dedup look at "layout compatible" in the standard.  For standard layout types there are decent guarantees involving casting pointers to classes with similar prefixes to each other and accessing said prefixes.  This requires standard layout, however, which is somewhat restrictive.